# Usecase for $emit rather than directly accessing parent scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm struggling to understand why you'd need to use $emit rather than using the controller as syntax and directly accessing & updating data on the parent scope. What are the use cases?

Comment: One thing that I can think of is there may be multiple parents listening for the event so it'd be easier to just $emit rather than parent1.update, parent2.update, parent3.update... etc. Also, it keeps your code a little more modularized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obviously more efficient to call a method on a parent scope directly, rather than using `$emit` (or `$broadcast`) to dispatch an event. But there are some valid reasons to do it.

Here's some reasons that come to mind:

- You want to emit an event that more than one application component can receive/process.
- You want to de-couple your components so that in the future the message may be processed by a different controller (or maybe a service or a directive, etc.).
- You want to emit an event that a service/factory can consume (these are not associated with any view/$scope, but you can inject the `$rootScope` into them).

Comment: Also add in could be triggered by dom event...or third party library event